# How to block events to be triggered on any element without stopPropogation or preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript

I want to block all events to be triggered on a particular element and all its child too.
I have shared code below, in which I have a button and one div having a "p" tag with default text. So I want on button click disable/block div with all child so even after I tried to modify any child elements or tried to trigger any event indirectly it should not get trigger. So in case of below code i don't want to modify default text on click

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
function modify(){

$("p").html("modified");
};

$("p").bind("click",modify);
function clickListner(){
$('#div *').attr('disabled', true);
$('div *').css("pointer-events","none");

modify();
};
</script>
<button onclick = "clickListner()">Show</button>
<div id="div"><p>default</p></div>




</body>
</html>
```

**Note** : Without using  stopPropogation or preventDefault()?

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself.

Comment: If you want to block all the events, the only way is to remove the element from the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with css.

```
pointer-events: none
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working. Sill children element get modified.